# SQL query print JSON data

Tags: php, sql, json

I am currently printing data from an SQL query using `print json_encode($query->result());`

Which is giving a result of all the fields in the database. It currently prints :

```
[{"id":"3812","assigned_to":"1","opportunity_id":null,"lead_stage":"1","first_name":"Jamie","last_name":"Warren","company_name":"","phone_number":"+1","email_address":"tobyalake@hotmail.com"},
```

However I need it to print in the following format :

```
items": [
    { "id":"3812"
```

How can i add the items part?

Answer (score 1):

You can just `json_encode` a new array with `$query->result()` assigned to a key of `'items'` like this:

```
print json_encode(['items' => $query->result()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap up with an array as like below

```
print json_encode(array('items' => $query->result()));
```

OR

```
$items_arr = array('items' => $query->result());
print json_encode($items_arr);
```